# C++ Template Classes

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a Computer Science student and we're currently studying `C++ Templates`.
We were instructed to write a `Linked List` template class and we are not allowed to use `STL`(note that this is unfinished code):

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    //////// NODE CLASS //////////
    template <class T>
    class Node
    {
    public:
        ///// DATA MEMBERS
        T *m_val;
        Node<T> *m_next;
        Node<T> *m_prev;
        // CTORS
        Node(T *val) : m_val(val) { m_next = NULL;  m_prev = NULL; }
        Node(T *val, Node<T> *next, Node<T> *prev) : m_val(val), m_next(next), m_prev(prev) { }
        // C.CTOR
        Node(const Node<T> & n) { m_val = n->m_val; m_next = n->m_next; m_prev = n->m_prev; }
        // DTOR
        ~Node() { delete m_val; if (m_prev) m_prev->m_next = m_next; if (m_next) m_next->m_prev = m_prev; }
    };
    ///////////////////////

    Node<T> *first;
public:
    LinkedList(T*)
    {

    }
    ~LinkedList();
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T* t)
{
    first = Node<T>(t); /// <---- PROBLEM HERE
}
```

However, the problem is that the compiler doesn't let me use the `Node` Constructor..

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

As I said, this is unfinished code, so I thought the error I'm getting would be confusing (because I couldn't see directly where the problem comes from).

Anyway, Here is the error (Debugging on Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Ex4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\dan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Ex4\Debug\Ex4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please add the error you're getting.

Comment: You get a +1 for being honest and having a try

Comment: To start with, `Node` shouldn't be a template.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `Node` to be a template. Or would you ever expect to have `LinkedList<T>::Node<U>` for different `T` and `U`?

Comment: Well you can't assign a `Node` to a `Node*`. You need a heap allocation here (`new`)

Comment: That error is unrelated to that line. You have an issue with your `main` function, for example, it might be missing.

Comment: @dyp I know, I did not write a main function, because this was just for the purpose of writing a template class. This is another reason why I did not post the error I got.

Comment: What do you expect if you don't have a main function? Don't even know why this post got upvoted.

Comment: Honestly, start *simpler*. Dynamic management of the `Node` objects will be complicated enough. You don't need to clutter it with half-dynamic management of `T`. Your node destructor does `delete m_val;`, yet there is *nothing* in this code that indicates nor guarantees the original pointer was ever dynamic. Don't store `T*`s. Store `T`s. And as mentioned, `Node` shouldn't be a template in the first place.

Comment: @user3175215 Every C++ program needs to have a main function. That's what the linker is telling you: it looked for a `main` function, but didn't found any => unresolved symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
first = Node<T>(t);
```

needs to be

```
first = new Node<T>(t);
```

since `first` is a `Node*`, not a `Node`.

You can also initialize it using:

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T* t) : first(new Node<T>(t))
{
}
```

which is a preferred approach.